# Ajax html editor extender converts Text and Tables to HTML on Page load

Tags: html, textbox

I use a HTML editor extender for a text box to let the users add tables and images to it. Also i have several other buttons on the page, upon clicking saves files attached, to the database.  But once the page loads with the button click the whole data in text box is converted into HTML.

Please let me know how to retain the contents in actual form.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="75" Rows="20" ></asp:TextBox>

<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender EnableSanitization="false" ID="HtmlEditor_tbDescription" TargetControlID="tbDescription" runat="server">
     <Toolbar>
         <ajaxToolkit:Undo />
         <ajaxToolkit:Redo />
         <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
         <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
         <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
         <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
         <ajaxToolkit:Subscript />
         <ajaxToolkit:Superscript />
         <ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />
         <ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter />
         <ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight />
         <ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
         <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
         <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
         <ajaxToolkit:CreateLink />
         <ajaxToolkit:UnLink />
         <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
         <ajaxToolkit:SelectAll />
         <ajaxToolkit:UnSelect />
         <ajaxToolkit:Delete />
         <ajaxToolkit:Cut />
         <ajaxToolkit:Copy />
         <ajaxToolkit:Paste />
         <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
         <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
         <ajaxToolkit:FontNameSelector />
         <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
         <ajaxToolkit:Indent />
         <ajaxToolkit:Outdent />
         <ajaxToolkit:InsertHorizontalRule />
         <ajaxToolkit:HorizontalSeparator />
         <ajaxToolkit:InsertImage />
     </Toolbar>
</ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```